# replace showModalDialog with jQuery UI , what is the best way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I am new in javascript and jQuery UI. Currently, I have to fix and improve the code from previous developer.

This is how the page should work: Using showModalDialog, a modal dialog box containing form will popup. There are some value passing from child page to the parent page.Also some value also will be display from the database.In short,this pop up dialog box is to search any item retrieved from database.

I wanted to find alternative for showModalDialog since it was deprecated. I have search and read some information on jQuery UI to replace the showModalDialog. However, before I started I would like to know the best way either to change all the related part in coding to jQuery UI or I can have some part only to change in the code. Which is the best?

The code:

```
function openWindow(win,address,curStatus){

var page = address;
var row = line;
var result = win.showModalDialog(page, selectedMaterial, "dialogHeight:400px;dialogWidth:700px;");
if (result == 'reload'){
  //do something
}else if (result==true){
  //do something
}else{
  //do something
}

}
```

Let me know if further explanation needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Currently Jquery UI is not best available solution, it better to use more powerful framework like ext.js or kendo ui, but if you like to use jquery ui is pretty simple but as far as I know it does not return a value on exit. you can simulate this behavior with clicking on a button for submit or exit or listen to close event something like this.

```
*$( "address" ).dialog({
     beforeClose: function( event, ui ) {}
   });*
```